# How To change Content using onChange in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

I have 2 types of content in DIVs. Default view is `div#BDT`. Now I want to change content using the SELECT.

```
<form method="post" action="domain_reseller.html">
    <p align="right">Choose Currency:</p>
    <select name="currency" onchange="submit()">
        <option value="1" selected="selected">BDT for Bangladesh</option>
        <option value="2">USD For World Wide Country</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div class="USD" id="USD">
    This Is USD Currency
</div>

<div class="BDT" id="BDT">
    This Is USD Currency
</div>
```

http://russelhost.com/domain_reseller.html

Comment: ***Do not*** use `<br>` tags inside a select.

Comment: @adeneo, revision history suggests *you* added the BRs!  ;)

Comment: @DerekHenderson - I did'nt, just indented the code to make it into "code".

Comment: @adeneo, yet the revision history shows otherwise.

Comment: @Ebrahim, did you want to submit the form, as the title suggests, or show/hide the currency DIV, as the question suggests?

Comment: @DerekHenderson - My revision history shows the BR's in the original question, so must be something wrong with your revision history ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by giving both your DIVs the same class, perhaps "currency", and make the value of the OPTIONs the same as the id of the DIVs:

```
<form method="post" action="domain_reseller.html">
    <p align="right">Choose Currency:</p>
    <select name="currency">
        <option value="BDT" selected="selected">BDT for Bangladesh</option>
        <option value="USD">USD For World Wide Country</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div class="currency" id="USD">
    This Is USD Currency
</div>
<div class="currency" id="BDT">
    This Is BDT Currency
</div>
```

Then in your CSS hide the currency div by default:

```
div.currency {
    display: none;
}
```

Then using jQuery display the currently selected currency, updating any time you select a different option:

```
var currencySelect = $('select');

$('#' + currencySelect.val()).show();

currencySelect.change(function () {
    $('div.currency').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HhtCs/)

Comment: in div tag have Lot's of content. so i want to view in DIV.

Comment: one More Problem right now.
Plz check http://localhost/russelhost/domain_reseller.html
change with refresh.

Comment: @Ebrahim, that's a link to `localhost`.  That means only someone on your computer can follow it!  Please either describe the problem or edit the fiddle I created.

Comment: when change it's show a problem. I'm used in Codeigniter FrameWork. Plz Check.
[link]http://russelhost.com/domain_reseller.html[/link]

Comment: That's because the select has `onchange="submit()"`.  Remove that.  That's causing your form to submit, and you don't want that.  (You can remove the form, too, unless you need it for something else.)

Answer (score 0):

How about using jQuery?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
//alert('Document is ready');
                $('select[name=currency]').change(function() {
                    var sel = $(this).val();
                    if (sel == 1) $('.report').html('Bangladeshi currency is required');
                    else  $('.report').html('USD currency is required');
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="domain_reseller.html">
    Choose Currency:<br>
    <select name="currency">
        <option value="1" selected>BDT for Bangladesh</option>
        <option value="2">USD For World Wide Country</option>
    </select>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<div class="report" id="report"></div>
<br>
<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Some notes:

1. You don't need to submit the form to change the content of a div based on the selected item.
2. You don't need two divs. One will do.  If you wish to have the two divs, you can show/hide the appropriate div like this:

   ```
   if (sel == 1) {
       $('#BDT').show();
       $('#USD').hide();
   }else{
       $('#USD').show();
       $('#BDT').hide();
   }
   ```

You can get some good tutorials on using jQuery [from here](http://phpacademy.org) or [from here](http://thenewboston.com)